# How can I click the tricky logout link and logout by using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, logout

Guys,

I met the webpage where the logout function was coded like this:

```
<div class="l login_even">
    <span class="logout">
        "("
            <a class="logoutBtn" href="javascript:void(0);">logout</a>
        ")"
    </span>
</div>
```

I can use the iteration of tagName "a" to locate the tag. 
However, I wanted to click the logout button and logout the webpage. 
I got error if I wrote down the code snippetsas follows:
script snippet:

```
If IEApp.Document.readyState="complete" Or IEApp.Document.readyState="loaded" Or IEApp.Document.readyState="interactive" Then
    Set objDoc = IEApp.Document
    Set allTags = objDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each aTag In allTags
        If aTag.innerHTML = "logout" Then
            WSH.Echo("Found!")
            aTag.click()
            objDoc.Location.Reload(True)
        'Else
            'WSH.Echo("Not Found!")
        End If
    Next
End If
```

error message:
**Line:28

Char:3

Error:Permission denied: 'innerHTML'

Code:800A0046

Source:Microsoft VBScript runtime error**

Could any guy help me? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I have the permission of administrator. I'm sure of that.

Comment: BTW, the line 28 is :If aTag.innerHTML = "logout" Then And I can get the "Found!" notification if the webpage really contains the "logout" .

Comment: Anyway, there's been no valuable answers until now. I found a method to fulfill the logout function. I used Wireshark to capture the real URI when I clicked the logout button. And I asked the IEBrowser to navigate the URI. That's done. However, I still got the same error saying Permission Denied. Just let it go temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Use `If aTag.innerText = "logout" Then` instead of innerHTML

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I got the same error and I couldn't logout.